# How to obtain median or mean value and dicotomize

Tags: r, statistics

I have filtered in R a Illumina Human Methylation 450K data into a dataframe of my cg's of interest. Look like this:

```
 head(x_filtered[1:3])

               TCGA-WB-A81T-01A TCGA-WB-A81G-01A TCGA-WB-A815-01A
cg12150457       0.12335296       0.10067159       0.13113157
cg07035961       0.17139128       0.31152824       0.04598332
cg01089834       0.07643279       0.11007415       0.05539685
cg11429969       0.10935966       0.29668556       0.09419880
cg10649903       0.10081063       0.43367623       0.07381163
cg26282566       0.13038106       0.08354794       0.10883622
```

I would like to make the mean value (or median?) of each rowname and create an event or vector event dividing the data into up- and down- the median (1 for upregulated or up-median, for example).cI would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: `?rowMeans` (or maybe `?colMeans`) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Your column names look like genes (and I am not sure what the row names are).  In that case, one would think you would be interested in mean/median of the columns. But your question doesn't suggest that. Infact, as above comment, it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Colnames are patients (TCGA barcodes) and rownames are CpG methylation sites, so Im interested in mean across rownames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use base R functions for this. Here 1 if the value of each column is greater than the mean of that gene / column.

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) +(x > mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

> ```
>            TCGA.WB.A81T.01A TCGA.WB.A81G.01A TCGA.WB.A815.01A
> cg12150457                1                0                1
> cg07035961                0                1                0
> cg01089834                0                1                0
> cg11429969                0                1                0
> cg10649903                0                1                0
> cg26282566                1                0                1
> ```

---

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) +(x > mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

> ```
>            TCGA.WB.A81T.01A TCGA.WB.A81G.01A TCGA.WB.A815.01A
> cg12150457                1                0                1
> cg07035961                1                1                0
> cg01089834                0                0                0
> cg11429969                0                1                1
> cg10649903                0                1                0
> cg26282566                1                0                1
> ```

Comment: See the new code added above the horizontal line. It seems that's what you are after. You can get the `rowMeans(df)` check if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can do this

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ +(. > mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

---

Or another option as based on the comments is

```
+(df > colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)[col(df)])
```

Comment: It returns true and false values